# Can these types of gradients be done in CSS?

Tags: css, compass-sass

I've seen the CSS gradient property and was wondering if these types of gradients can be done cross browser with either Compass or vanilla CSS? I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

[image]

Comment: Well what have you tried so far? Did you look at MDN, specs, etc? Are there any other questions on SO that make you wonder, leave you with specific questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they can:

```
background: rgb(252,215,51);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(252,215,51,1) 50%, rgba(246,185,51,1) 50%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(50%,rgba(252,215,51,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(246,185,51,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(252,215,51,1) 50%,rgba(246,185,51,1) 50%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(252,215,51,1) 50%,rgba(246,185,51,1) 50%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(252,215,51,1) 50%,rgba(246,185,51,1) 50%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(252,215,51,1) 50%,rgba(246,185,51,1) 50%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcd733', endColorstr='#f6b933',GradientType=0 );
```

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/KueLJ/1/

Note: generated using http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend this gradient editor:

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

You can easily do a number of different and complicated gradients using css.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple, clean and convenient solution with Compass: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HCexj